# How to exit a loop in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I want to make the loop stops when `x + y =z`, on the else.

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Nov 16 18:39:40 2015

@author: gabri
"""

from random import randint
import os

x = randint(1,11)
y = randint(1,11)

print ("", x,"+", y,"=\n")
z = int(input("Resposta="))

if z == x + y:
    input ("\n\nCorreto\nPrima enter para continuar...")

else:
    for z in range(0, 10):
        os.system('CLS')
        input ("Incorreto.\n\n Tente de novo...")
        x = randint(1,11)
        y = randint(1,11)
        os.system('CLS')
        print ("", x,"+", y,"=\n")
        z = int(input("Resposta="))
        if z == x + y: # I want the loop to exit here
            input ("\n\nCorreto\nPrima enter para continuar...")
            exit
```

Comment: What's supposed to happen if the user never give a correct answer?  This code just falls out of the loop.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Replace `exit` with `break`. `Exit` isn't a way to exit loops in Python.

[break statement docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: `exit` is a built-in function.  If it "weren't a thing," you'd get a syntax error.

Comment: Edited. Glad you caught that. I could have mislead generations.